# Running groovy-maven-plugin within POM packaged project

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I want to run groovy scripts as part of parent POM which has `POM` packaging.
I set `maven-groovy-plugin` configured as follows:

```xml
<groupId>org.sct</groupId>
<artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>app</name>
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <source>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy/check-xsl-id.groovy</source>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

However the script is not executed during the build.
If I run the goal individually `mvn groovy:execute` it works fine.

How can I bind plugin execution to a POM packaging phase?

Comment: actually, everything should work fine for such configuration unless it is `<pluginManagement>` configuration.

Comment: That was my understanding as well

Comment: Actually @AndreyB.Panfilov - you are absolutely right... The POM configuration was incorrect - it used `<pluginManagement>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<plugin>` instead of `<pluginManagement>` for plugin configuration works perfectly well.